# wp query not working with custom post type > category

Tags: html, custom-post-type, wordpress

I'm using html5-blank for my theme.

all queries work fine when pulling from standard wordpress post type... it breaks when trying to pull from 'html5-blank' post type.

Here's the query:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=spotlight&showposts=2');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
    <!-- pull thumbnail image -->
    <article class="article_wrap">
        <div class="widget_thumb">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>
        <h1 class="widget_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <p class="widget_spot_description"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

here's functions.php:

```
function create_post_type_html5()
{
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'html5-blank'); // Register Taxonomies for Category
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'html5-blank');
register_post_type('html5-blank', // Register Custom Post Type
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'), // Rename these to suit
        'singular_name' => __('HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'html5blank'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),
        'edit' => __('Edit', 'html5blank'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),
        'new_item' => __('New HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),
        'view' => __('View HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),
        'view_item' => __('View HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),
        'search_items' => __('Search HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),
        'not_found' => __('No HTML5 Blank Custom Posts found', 'html5blank'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No HTML5 Blank Custom Posts found in Trash', 'html5blank')
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'thumbnail'
    ), 

    'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
    'taxonomies' => array(
        'post_tag',
        'category'
    ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
));


}
```

I'm checking the category box in the custom post type but the query does not populate the post. It only shows the posts from the standard post type.

**Noooooooo!**

Comment: `showposts` has been long time depreciated!. You should be using `posts_per_page`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the post type in the wp query:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=spotlight&posts_per_page=2&post_type=html5-blank');
```

Edit: replaced deprecated showposts  by posts_per_page

Comment: Thanks! That works. Man, I must of had some tired eyes! Now, why in the world is that post type not in the main query?

Comment: `showposts` has been long time depreciated!. You should be using `posts_per_page`